# Why do DKIM public keys always end with 'IDAQAB'?

Tags: dkim, opendkim

I have noticed that all the DKIM public keys generated always end with the string 'IDAQAB'.
Any reason to it or are there cases where DKIM public keys will not end with the same string all the time ?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DKIM public keys are encoded in the binary [DER format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) and shared as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) in the [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System). [RSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) public keys consist of a modulus and an exponent. The exponent is typically [65537](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Faulty_key_generation), which is `01 00 01` in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal). DER prefixes this value with `02` for the [integer type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#Types) and `03` for the [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#Length_octets) of the exponent in bytes. The Base64 encoding of `02 03 01 00 01` is `IDAQAB` (at the right offset).

Before the modulus, which is unique for each RSA public key, there are nested length prefixes and an object identifier. This information is identical for RSA keys of the same length, which is why you find many DKIM public keys which also share the same prefix, such as `MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA`.